# Take second of three numbers from a line in a file

Tags: string, perl

I have a text file with a line that I'm trying to get a certain number from.

There are some numbers at the beginning of the line, in the middle, and the end. The one I need is in the middle.

Is there a way to get the middle number? Perhaps ignoring everything up to and following it?

Example of a line:

```
my $astring = "cool more 23423 random words of 1234 random other [wordssssssss] 23";
```

So in the above example, I would like to take the `1234` that follows `of`.

Comment: You are lucky to get any answers at all, as Stack Overflow isn't a place to farm out your work and get it done for free. If you're really in a position where you can't even begin to write your own solution then you should be employing someone who can, not freeloading from the internet. That is probably why your question has two down votes and a close vote (none of which are mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is extract all numbers, then use the second one:

```
my $astring = "cool more 23423 random words of 1234 random other [wordssssssss] 23";

my @numbers = $astring =~ /[0-9]+/g;
print "The second number is $numbers[1]\n";
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
my ($second_num) = $astring =~ /^\D*\d+\D+(\d+)/;
```

or

```
my $second_num = ( $astring =~ /\d+/g )[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific, so any solution that grabs one of the numbers out of a string may be correct for you

For instance, what would you want from a value like this?

```
$astring = 'a2b3c 45g 12 12/3'
```

This solution splits the whole string on whitespace, and selects into `@nums` only those "words" that contain at least one digit and no non-digit characters. It then prints the second of these found

Depending on exactly what variation you expect in the input data this may or may not be sufficient

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $astring = "cool more 23423 random words of 1234 random other [wordssssssss] 23";

my @nums = grep { /\d/ and not /\D/ } split ' ', $astring;

print $nums[1], "\n";
```

#### output

```
1234
```